# Game Maker Studio 2, Google Cloud saving

Tags: cloud, game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I have been trying to get Google Cloud saving to work in GSM2 but every time I hit load or save -buttons, the game crashes with "app has stopped working" -message. 
I am following this tutorial: https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/cloud-saving-on-android.27685/

I've tried everything but I can't figure out why it's crashing.
Anyone knows what might be a problem?

Has anyone got google cloud saving to work in GSM2?